# Getting Sum within join and group by query

Tags: sql

I am Querying my online store, I am using a group and join to count how many orders are DVD orders by checking the products delivery_format field.

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT 
      account_asset.product_group_id,
      product_group.product_code,
      product_group.name,
      product_group.conference_year,
      product_group.delivery_format,
      product_group.id,
      count(*) AS myCount
  FROM account_asset
  INNER JOIN product_group ON product_group.id = account_asset.product_group_id
  GROUP BY account_asset.product_group_id
  ORDER BY product_group.conference_year,
         product_group.product_code,
         myCount
```

How can I get a total SUM on the 'myCount' field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select from that result set:

```
select sum (mycount)
from
(select 
account_asset.product_group_id,
product_group.product_code, 
product_group.name,
product_group.conference_year,
product_group.delivery_format,
product_group.id,
count(*) as myCount
from account_asset 
inner join product_group ON product_group.id = account_asset.product_group_id
group by account_asset.product_group_id 
order by product_group.conference_year,product_group.product_code,myCount) T1
```

Comment: My Co-worker shared this with me today. Initially, the syntax was not clear, but I get it now. Thanks you other guys, even tho you were a bit 'over my head'

Answer (score 0):

FYI: You can't order by an alias like you are attempting to do with ORDER BY MyCount. See correction below.

Regarding your question, i'm assuming you want the total on each line. So do this:

```
SELECT account_asset.product_group_id,
       product_group.product_code,
       product_group.name,
       product_group.conference_year,
       product_group.delivery_format,
       product_group.id,
       count(1) AS myCount,
       SUM((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM account_asset INNER JOIN product_group ON product_group.id = account_asset.product_group_id)) AS MyTotal
FROM account_asset
INNER JOIN product_group
    ON product_group.id = account_asset.product_group_id
GROUP BY account_asset.product_group_id
ORDER BY product_group.conference_year,
         product_group.product_code,
         count(1)
```

However, you're a lot better off defining a variable in a stored procedure, as the above may recalculate for each row (check the query plan).

So, in a sproc do this:

```
DECLARE @Total = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM account_asset INNER JOIN product_group ON product_group.id = account_asset.product_group_id)

SELECT account_asset.product_group_id,
       product_group.product_code,
       product_group.name,
       product_group.conference_year,
       product_group.delivery_format,
       product_group.id,
       count(1) AS myCount,
       @Total AS myTotal
FROM account_asset
INNER JOIN product_group
    ON product_group.id = account_asset.product_group_id
GROUP BY account_asset.product_group_id
ORDER BY product_group.conference_year,
         product_group.product_code,
         count(1)
```

Also... if you want to make it even more efficient change the query that calculates the total into a semi-join instead of a join. ie. use a correlated sub query. It's much faster because all your doing is checking for existence of the account_asset in the product_group.

```
     SELECT COUNT(1)
     FROM account_asset a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_group p WHERE p.id = a.product_group_id)
```

Comment: I tried the non-stored-proc way, no good. the totals look crazy.

Comment: You might have to remove the sum... and add the derived in-line query to the group by to get it to look the way you want.

Though, my guess is that's going to be very inefficient looking in your query plan.

Comment: Let me know if that worked so I can update my answer.